# How to store large amount of data locally (in the browser) - or enable recent data sync between local <-> server?

Tags: sqlite, local-storage, data-synchronization

I have developed an application that needs to keep data sync'd locally (within the browser) and the server.
The server data is mySQL and the local data is in form of any available persistent storage (localStorage, SQLite, IndexDB etc.).  But all these locally stored data have limitation of space (sometimes 5MB and sometime a bit more).
I am looking for something that may not have any limitation - or a custom design system that can create multiple instances of local storage for 1 application.  Is this possible ?

The other way, I thought it could work (but I have not knowledge of a system / library that can do this) is something that will sync only the most recent amount of data with the local storage - and keep the older data on the server and only when called it can update itself.  Is there a library in PHP/JS that can do this (something like facebook - the most recent data shows up fast, but as we scroll to older data it will download chuncks of data locally ?

I hope this is clear ...  Thanks for your suggestions in advance.